# How can I make interactive coding videos like Khan Academy?

Tags: javascript, streaming

Take a look at [this link](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/sql/relational-queries-in-sql/p/joining-related-tables-with-left-outer-joins). Has anyone open-sourced a way to create interactive coding videos like this? Is any other website doing what Khan Academy is doing? If I wanted to make videos like this, how should I go about doing it (I'm a programmer)?

Is it easier just to apply to Khan Academy?